# Obter as dimensões duma elemento (caixa) de imagem

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

No SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services), será que existe alguma maneira de saber as dimensões de um elemento de imagem (uma caixa de imagem) no relatório, em tempo de execução ("runtime"), na secção *Code* do relatório?

O meu objetivo é centrar ou alinhar à direita uma imagem obtida da base de dados quando o relatório é executado, e isso é bem possível utilizando Padding.Left e Padding.Top da imagem, se a largura e a altura do elemento de imagem no relatório forem conhecidas, usando o método descrito [aqui](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/nathaneccles/2014/04/15/ssrs-right-and-centre-align-images-in-a-table/) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30705958/303101). Mas em vez de codificar o tamanho do elemento de imagem, quero obtê-lo da definição do próprio relatório de alguma forma, para que o alinhamento se ajuste corretamente se o elemento de imagem for alterado posteriormente, por exemplo, por um utilizador.

Comment: **Observações do usuário**: *Agradeço com antecedência pela vossa ajuda (e desculpem por favor o meu português imperfeito!)*

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2978/rendering-images-from-a-database-on-ssrs-reports/

Comment: @AugustoVasques Muito obrigado! Assim, recuperar a imagem da base de dados (como descrito no link que enviou), e calcular o Padding.Left e o Padding.Top para a alinhar na caixa de imagem, já sao problemas resolvidos. A minha pergunta é sobre saber o tamanho do elemento (caixa) de imagem a partir da definição do relatório, para que a largura e a altura não precisem de ser codificadas no cálculo.